# Hadoop YARN Default schedular

Tags: default, scheduler, hadoop-yarn

Does Hadoop YARN have a default scheduler ?

Wondering what if yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class is not set in conf/yarn-site.xml?

Comment: I think I got this one . the default Scheduler is FIFO

Answer (score 4):

**yarn-defualt.xml** specifies the value of property: **yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class** = **org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler**.

[yarn-default.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml)

Hence, if you do not specify the scheduler property in yarn-site.xml then CapacityScheduler is used as default,

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of future readers of this question:

Different distributions have affinity to different schedulers by default which can be overridden .

The following information about leading distributions is accurate as of the time of writing:

- Hortonworks (v2.x) - Capacity Schedulers
- Cloudera (v5.x) - Fair Schedulers
- MAPR (v5.x) - Fair Schedulers
- Big Insights (v2.x) - InfoSphere BigInsights Scheduler (average
  response time metrics)
- Pivotal HD (v3.x) - Capacity Schedulers

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String DEFAULT_RM_SCHEDULER = 
  "org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler";


String schedulerClassName = conf.get(YarnConfiguration.RM_SCHEDULER,
    YarnConfiguration.DEFAULT_RM_SCHEDULER);
LOG.info("Using Scheduler: " + schedulerClassName);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks